# How to call function with paramaters from Jquery to Ruby

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby, ajax, function

I have function in Ruby

```
 def connection       
      host = 'localhost'
      port = 80
 end
```

And there I calling function

```
<script>
$.get('/app/Test/connection', { });  
</script>
```

I need call function with parameters.
Ruby will looks like

```
def connection (host1, port1)
      host = host1
      port = port1
end
```

How will looks like calling function with parameters in Jquery? I need something like that

```
/app/Test/connection('localhost', 80)
```

Comment: Do you use a framework like *Ruby on Rails* or *Sinatra*? Or how did you implement the server?

Comment: Thank for your reaction. Please, don't think, its some connection to server. I'm learning how to call function with parameters and this is my example. And I'm using Ruby, version 1.9.2. (ruby-doc.org)

Comment: @Revolt, certainly a server side 'framework' is needed in this context. Just executing your Ruby script won't work. You can't just call Ruby functions from your jQuery code without some kind of framework (not necessarily a third party framework).

Comment: Well, you can use CGI or some such @enrmarc ... It's useful to learn how the low-level stuff works on which Sinatra and Rails are built ;-) Ruby comes with the [CGI](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/cgi/rdoc/CGI.html) library for this.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker and isn't CGI some kind of framework? In the original sense of the word ;)

Comment: @enrmarc Well, I would call it more of a library than a framework, but lets not get too semantic about these things ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is my solution.

```
<script>
var a = 'localhost'
var b = 80
$.get('/app/Test/connection', { value:a, value2:b});  
</script>
```

Ruby:

```
def connection 
      @host = @params['value']
      @port = @params['value2']
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to call a url from jQuery with params like:

```
$.get('localhost:3000/connection/test/hostHere/portHere', { });
```

Then in routes.rb:

```
get 'connection/test/:host/:port'
```

Then in connection_controller.rb:

```
def test
  host = params[:host]
  port = params[:post]
  # some more test logic here
end
```

Comment: This assumes Rails... Not all Ruby is Rails ;-)